# The Bluetooth output from my Phone is not correctly evaluated on the ESP32

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32

This code should make the internal Led of my ESP32 turn on/off, instead the led just blinks up (it is probably just the confirmation that the ESP received an output or the code). The connection between the ESP32 and my smartphone is done via the "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" (an app found in the Google Playstore).

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
 
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  if(!SerialBT.begin("ESP32")){
    Serial.println("An error occurred initializing Bluetooth");
  }
}
 
void loop() {

 while(SerialBT.available()){
    Serial.println(SerialBT.read()); 
  }
  delay(50);
  
  if (Serial.available()) { // if there is data coming
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); // read string until newline character

    if (command == "ON") {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); // turn on LED
      Serial.println("Turn LED ON");
    } else if (command == "OFF") {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);  // turn off LED
      Serial.println("Turn LED OFF");
    }
  }
}
```

I have written the right command (ON/OFF) to the ESP32 via the App and I expected the internal LED to Turn on with the "ON" command and stay like this until I enter the "OFF" command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that you get the text you expect at all? It is quite common to have the wrong serial settings. For example, are you certain that the app is writing at 115,200 baud? I would typically recommend starting at 9600 baud (which is extremely commonly supported) and working up. If you have a wired UART connection, you should log the information you're getting to make sure it's what you expect. I also sometimes write it to external storage if you have some, for debugging purposes.

Comment: Well, i did it slightly different as above, so i found a way anyway